# How to implement using NHibernate UInt64 identifier generator with the option to set its initialize value

Tags: nhibernate, identifier

Is it possible to use NHibernate for getting unique identifier of type: UInt64.
The initialize value of this property must be unique (for more than 1 DB).
The usage: I need to get this value and increment it by 1.
This action should be a closed transaction.

Comment: How do you know this will produce a unique value across db's?

Comment: Does Hace's answer make sense to you? Guids are useful for cross-database identification of records (e.g. for synchronization).

Comment: GertArnold - Today we do it by raffling a Uint64 number:  The probability to get the same InitNumber in more than 1 DB is very low. Currently we do it now as follows:                                             var buffer = new byte[sizeof(UInt64)];
new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
UInt64 firstIdentifier = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);

Comment: Ok, so it boils down to creating a custom Id generator, as there are no combined db reads. I think [this](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/creating-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate.aspx) is a useful link for you.

Comment: @GertArnold, thanks for the link - I will try to implement it and tell you how it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually we want to have unique keys in one DB, not for multiple databases, GUIDs are used there as far as I know. Getting the max(int64) out of both DBs and then picking the largests and adding 1 will work but that sounds rather clumsy I think? What do you need this for actually?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Uint64 is required by 3rd party application which refuse to use GUID. These unique numbers are used in more than 1 DB. We need the lowest probability in order to get the same initialized number. we can't compare between 2 DBs

Answer (score 0):

What about using database identities (or similar) and setting the starting value for database N as N, and the increment by value (how much you add to the current latest key every time you get a new one) equal to the number of databases?

That way each database should keep a distinct set of ids. Only problem would be in case you need to add a new database to the set.